# I opened blender and when I went to scale my cube the module doesn't show up

Tags: modeling

I opened up blender and went to scale my object and the module thing (completely forgot what it is called) doesn't show so I can't scale my object the way i want[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled the *Show Gizmo* option?

[image]

Comment: I'm sitting here confused as to why this button was off in the first place, it happened randomly thank you so much lmaooo